# Unable to launch ssh slave connection in latest Jenkins to Redhat 7.9 due to Received Junk Text error

Tags: jenkins, ssh, redhat, slave

Error follows.  LogLevel on server is set to QUIET so debug should be off. There is nothing in .bashrc or .profile that would generate any text at login.  I have tried several different settings in sshd_config to try and suppress the messages, but nothing seems to change. Direct ssh from the Windows command line connects just fine, but has the same junk text.

```
SSHLauncher{host='192.168.86.38', port=22, credentialsId='b7cce8cd-3f30-48f4-97e7-ca0511ce35fd', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[04/05/21 11:01:03] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.86.38:22.
[04/05/21 11:01:03] [SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.

[04/05/21 11:01:05] [SSH] Authentication successful.
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 124
debug3: Copy environment: XDG_SESSION_ID=19
debug3: Copy environment: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
Environment:
  USER=curt
  LOGNAME=curt
  HOME=/home/curt
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
  MAIL=/var/mail/curt
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=192.168.86.5 51847 22
  SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.86.5 51847 192.168.86.38 22
  XDG_SESSION_ID=19
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000

null
[04/05/21 11:01:06] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[04/05/21 11:01:06] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the entries in the '.profile' and/or '.bashrc' that are doing things which are not allowed in a non-interactive shell.  Either that, or wrap them in conditionals which prevent them from being executed in a non-interactive shell.

For more details refer [link](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-Launch-an-Agent-getting-quot-received-junk-text-is-as-follows-stdin-is-not-a-tty-quot-td4962632.html)